# rails sort_by string with empty string latest

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
 foot = [{val: "left"}, {val: "right"}, {val: nil}]
 foot.sort_by{ |f| f[:val].to_s } 
 => [{:val=>nil}, {:val=>"left"},{:val=>"right"}]
```

How do I sort such array descеnded with nil-elements at the end of the list?
=> left, right, nil

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious thing is to separate array into 2 parts: with nil values, and the other:

```
foot = [{val: "left"}, {val: "right"}, {val: nil}]
nil_array, str_array = foot.partition { |h| h[:val].nil? }
str_array.sort_by{ |f| f[:val].to_s }.concat(nil_array)
```

If it were numbers, I would also suggested something like:

```
foot.sort_by { |f| f[:val] ? f[:val] : Float::INFINITY }
```

Comment: "if it were numbers" - except -9999999 would sort __first__ :)

Comment: Better, but not big enough. Make it `Float::INFINITY`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sort` to compare pairs of values and handle `nil` values explicity in the comparisons.

```
foot = [{val: "left"}, {val: "right"}, {val: nil}]
foot.sort{ |a,b| a[:val].nil? ? 1 : ( b[:val].nil? ? -1 : a[:val] <=> b[:val]) }
=> [{:val=>"left"},{:val=>"right"},{:val=>nil}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Shorter one:

```
foot.sort_by { |a| [a[:val] ? '' : ' ', a[:val].to_s] }
```